# How to find module of Integer(Generic) in Java

Tags: java, generics, linked-list

I have Dual `LinkedList` (`DLL`) that I wanna separate in two `DLL`s, one with only odd numbers and the other with even. But I'm getting error when I try to `((Generic)%2==0)`

Error Message: The method `parseInt(E)` is undefined for the type `DLL<E>`

```
public DLL parni() {
    DLL<E>niza = new DLL<E>();
    DLLNode<E>tmp = first;

    while(tmp.succ != null) {
        if((parseInt(tmp.element)) % 2 != 0) {
            niza.insertLast(tmp.element);
            delete(tmp);
        }
        tmp = tmp.succ;
    }
}
```

*tmp.element is generic of type E*

By the way, I tried adding the super class Number in the `DLL` class

```
class DLL<E extends Number>
```

Any advices?

Comment: You should use tmp.element.intValue() instead.

Comment: What's wrong with it? [It compiles](https://ideone.com/dU2zMI) (I added `first` and a return value to the method)

Comment: @victini thanks man it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If E extends java.lang.Number, you can try like this:

```
if(tmp.element.intValue() % 2 != 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple: you wrote your own class `DLL<E extends Number>`.

Now you wrote code that intends to call a method `parseInt()` **belonging** to your own class DLL.

The compiler is telling you:

> The method parseInt(E) is undefined for the type DLL

that you didn't write that method yet.

In other words: if you intend to have a method with that name on **your own** class, then you have to add such a method to your class. So far, that `E` generic parameter isn't of any significance. Like any other method you intend to call on an object, that method must exist on the corresponding class.

Beyond that: do not use names such as "DLL". Don't abbreviate class names. Their names communicate to human readers, and DLL communicates nothing. Call it DualLinkedList for example.

Comment: For a second I thought you were wrong about the name 'DLL'. After reading OP's question I thought it was representing a dynamic-link library (and the URL class is not named UniformResourceLocator, after all). So yeah, that demonstrates perfectly how misleading the name is in this instance.